# Upload file with node.js, get more than one file

Tags: node.js

I have this code in order to upload single file with node.js, using express and multer:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var fs = require("fs");
var multer  = require('multer');
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });

// Process upload file
app.post('/file_upload', upload.single('single-file'), function(request, response) {

    var fileName = request.file.originalname;
    var filePath = request.file.path;
    var file = __dirname + "/uploads/" +  fileName;

    fs.readFile(filePath, function(err, data) {
        fs.writeFile(file, data, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                responseData = {
                    'message' : 'File uploaded successfully',
                    'fileName' : fileName
                };
            }

            response.end(JSON.stringify(responseData));
        })
    });
});
```

Here is the HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>File Uploading Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>File Upload:</h3>
        Select a file to upload: <br />
        <form action="http://localhost:8081/file_upload" method="POST" 
      enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="single-file" size="50" />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

After running the code, I was able to uploaded file.
But the problem is, I keep getting 2 files uploaded in my "uploads" folder each time. One file with the original name, and one with strange name like 2787ab2db292d90bd2da83a6a6ce1700.

Is that normal? How can I get rid of the other file when upload?

Comment: add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form

Comment: I did that in my HTML already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is You're creating new file from already uploaded file.
so solution is to rename uploaded file with temporary name to original name:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var fs = require("fs");
var multer  = require('multer');
var uploadsFolder = __dirname + '/uploads/';  // defining real upload path
var upload = multer({ dest: uploadsFolder }); // setting path for multer

// Process upload file
app.post('/file_upload', upload.single('single-file'), function(request, response) {

    var fileName = request.file.originalname; // original file name
    var file = request.file.path; // real file path with temporary name

    // renaming real file to it's original name
    fs.rename(file, uploadsFolder + fileName, function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        response.json({success:false, message: err});
        return;
      }

      response.json({success:true, message: 'File uploaded successfully', fileName: fileName});
    });
});
```

or make multer to upload to temporary folder and then copy or move to uploads folder:

install fs extra:

```
npm install --save fs.extra
```

and

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs.extra'); // extra functionality
var multer  = require('multer');
var uploadsFolder = __dirname + '/uploads/';  // defining real upload path
var tempFolder = __dirname + '/tmp/'; // folder for temporary files, must exist
var upload = multer({ dest: tempFolder }); // setting path for multer

// Process upload file
app.post('/file_upload', upload.single('single-file'), function(request, response) {

    var fileName = request.file.originalname; // original file name
    var file = request.file.path; // real file path with temporary name

    // renaming real file to it's original name
    fs.move(file, uploadsFolder + fileName, function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        response.json({success:false, message: err});
        return;
      }

      response.json({success:true, message: 'File uploaded successfully', fileName: fileName});
    });
});
```

Comment: Work like a charm! tks for that. But why you use 'fs.extra' instead of 'fs'. Is that because fs.copy?

Comment: Yes. fs extra has copy, move and etc. functions that comes handy. For example You're creating file, reading from source and writing to destination. It does the same, but You only use fs.copy, that makes Your code short. Fs.move is combination of copy, rename and delete.